# Why is my case script not piping unless I supply an explicit path to the script?

Tags: bash, pipe, case

I'm in charge of tape backups at my workplace.
I'm generating a command to pipe into our backup program's command console, using a case statement.
it echoes the proper command into the Command Console of the program, based on the argument I supply the script.

I've placed the script in my ~/bin folder so that it can be in my path, with all my other scripts which all work fine.

However, if use it normally as such:

`[me@server ~]$ SSlots Robot1`

My command console acts like Im not using the console command right, and returns it's own error output:

```
[me@server ~]$ SSlots Robot1
Copyright (C) yadda yadda

Version: 12.0.5 (compiled yadda yadda) version number yadda yadda Enterprise release

Usage: cconsole yadda yadda
```

If however I explicitly state my path as such:

`[me@server ~]$ ./bin/SSlots Robot1`

it behaves properly and performs the operation as the script created.

```
Connecting to Robot1:Foo
Enter a period to cancel a command.
status slots storage=Robot1 drive=0
Issuing command.
Device "Robot1" has a number of slots.
Connecting to Storage
Issuing command.
 Slot |   Volume Name    |   Status  |     Media Type       |      Pool          |
------+------------------+-----------+----------------------+--------------------|
    1 |      foo         |   foo     |      foo             |      foo           |
```

Likewise, if I'm already cd *into* my bin folder and run it, it behaves

I've looked through my case statement, and my punctuation, I've fiddled with quotes and placement of my semicolons, but everything seems to remain the same no matter what I do.
Clearly *something* is getting piped into the Control Console, because it's the *Control Console*, that returns the error; not bash.

I'm very confused. I'd love to understand what the path to the SCRIPT has to do with how the Script pipes its output into the *Command Console*, and how to do this without stating a path.

A minimalistic paste of the code, is below

```
#!/bin/bash
Robot=$1
case $Robot in
        "robot1")
                echo "status slots storage=Robot1 drive=0" | ControlConsole ;;
        "robot2")
                echo "status slots storage=Robot2 drive=0" | ControlConsole ;;
        "robot3")
                echo "status slots storage=Robot3 drive=0" | ControlConsole ;;
        *)
                echo
                echo        "Error: Cannot find  a Robot named \"$Robot\"."
                echo
esac
```

Comment: I can't think of any way it could make a difference to the script you showed. The only difference should be in the value of `$0` -- do you ever reference that in the full script?

Comment: The first step in debugging shell scripts is to put `set -x` at the beginning. Then you'll see a transcript of every command as it's executed, with variables expanded.

Comment: You're giving the argument `Robot1`, but the script expects `robot1`. `case` is case-sensitive.

Comment: I don't ever reference $0
the only 0 in the script is in those quotes to echo 'drive=0' into ControlConsole
I figured case would be case sensitive, since it's creating a variable, but where I put "robot#" here, the full script puts in the names of the robots as the backup program knows them; also regardless as the case, It's putting the same values into the command; the only difference, is where I'm running the script from

Comment: Did you try `set -x` to see what's going on?

Comment: You may need to post the full script. Your minimal version doesn't show anything that could cause this problem, so it must be in something you left out.

Answer (score 0):

Per Barmar's suggestion, I added set -x to the script.

When I ran the script again from my path: `[me@server ~]$ SSlot`

It returned the exact same results. No change whatsoever.

However specifying an explicit path: `[me@server ~]$ ./bin/SSlots`

produced the proper results WITH debugging.

That got me thinking; I've done a lot with aliases on this server too.
I took a peek in my ~/.bashrc and sure enough, I had tried long ago, to to achieve this with an alias of the same name.

I removed the alias, and the script behaves appropriately with or without an explicit path. Turns out, this was a simple, User Error.